# Columns goes downwards in some pages

Tags: css

I am currently working with wooCommerce. After i try to add some products to my page. Columns goes downwards as you can see here: http://citereja.pe.hu/nb/produktai/ I have checked all the properties and only if I change line-height to 0% columns are displayed in one line. But if I do that it ruins other things so its not a good solution. I don't know why but in my other page it displays propertly: http://citereja.pe.hu/lt/apie-mus/

I am sorry for not being very specific, because I am not sure where the problem is. Thank you

Comment: I could only glance at it a minute. But using web inspector it looks like your images are exceeding the constraints of the anchor tag. The anchor is blank above the image. http://i.imgur.com/cQI27Ur.png.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)